# reading the numbers from a flat text files in R

Tags: json, r

I have a text file with the following lines:

```
{"time":"2015-11-15T17:56:45.300","x":93.32,"y":8.6,"s":4.57,"dis":0.45,"on_field":true,"game":{"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":2015111500}]},"team":{"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":"5110"}]},"play":{"references":[{"origin":"ngs","id":""}]},"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":"00-0026189"}]}
{"time":"2015-11-15T17:56:45.400","x":93.77,"y":8.48,"s":4.55,"dis":0.47,"on_field":true,"game":{"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":2015111500}]},"team":{"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":"5110"}]},"play":{"references":[{"origin":"ngs","id":""}]},"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":"00-0026189"}]}
{"time":"2015-11-15T17:56:45.500","x":94.23,"y":8.36,"s":4.53,"dis":0.47,"on_field":true,"game":{"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":2015111500}]},"team":{"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":"5110"}]},"play":{"references":[{"origin":"ngs","id":""}]},"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":"00-0026189"}]}
{"time":"2015-11-15T17:56:45.600","x":94.67,"y":8.23,"s":4.51,"dis":0.46,"on_field":true,"game":{"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":2015111500}]},"team":{"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":"5110"}]},"play":{"references":[{"origin":"ngs","id":""}]},"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":"00-0026189"}]}
{"time":"2015-11-15T17:56:45.700","x":95.1,"y":8.08,"s":4.5,"dis":0.46,"on_field":true,"game":{"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":2015111500}]},"team":{"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":"5110"}]},"play":{"references":[{"origin":"ngs","id":""}]},"references":[{"origin":"gsis","id":"00-0026189"}]}
```

I am trying to extract the `date`, `time`, `x`, `y`, `s`, and `dis` variables and save them in an R data frame. I think I can find a way to clean it with a shell script then read it in R  but I was hoping there is some nice trick to do this in R only. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Each of your lines appear to be in JSON format (but not the whole file, so we cannot just parse it as such). You could return each line as a list and then make a list of the results

```
res <- readLines("test.txt")
library(jsonlite)
allofit <- sapply(res, fromJSON)
```

which will give you a list of lists (of lists ..) containing all your data

Comment: Thank you. After seeing the output, I guess the best approach is to use awk and sed to chop the data into a more manageable form.